# Как при запуске контейнера сделать запись в /etc/hosts?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

При запуске контейнера я подменяю docker-php-entrypoint.sh.
В файле есть код, который записывает в /etc/hosts ip host.docker.internal

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

HOST_DOMAIN="host.docker.internal"
if ! ping -q -c1 $HOST_DOMAIN > /dev/null 2>&1
  then
 HOST_IP=$(ip route | awk 'NR==1 {print $3}')
 # shellcheck disable=SC2039
 echo -e "$HOST_IP\t$HOST_DOMAIN" >> /etc/hosts
fi

#first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
  set -- php-fpm "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Также меняю пользователя от которого запускается контейнер с root на app

```
FROM php:8.1-cli-alpine

....................................

COPY ./common/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint

RUN addgroup -g 1000 app && adduser -u 1000 -G app -s /bin/sh -D app

WORKDIR /app

USER app
```

В docker-compose.yml

```
php-cli:
build:
  context: ./project/docker
  dockerfile: development/php-cli/Dockerfile
volumes:
  - ./project:/app
```

Запуск контейнера завершается ошибкой "Permission denied"

В общем то понятно, что пользователь app не имеет прав на запись в /etc/hosts.

Пробовал запустить docker-php-entrypoint через RUN сразу после установки прав на исполнение и перед созданием пользователя app - ошибка "Read-only file system".
Пытался использовать su в docker-php-entrypoint, результата не добился.

Как можно решить эту проблему, чтобы контейнер запускался от app, но при этом можно было сделать запись в /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно чтобы `host.docker.internal` указывало на хост, то на `Linux` вы можете использовать при запуске контейнера `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` или в `docker-compose.yml` (но уровне нужного сервиса):

```yaml
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

На `Windows` и `MacOS` это работает автоматически.

Comment: Благодарю. Вроде заработало как надо, хотя я не всё проверил.
Как всё просто оказалось. Подскажите, что содержит в себе host-gateway? 
Я просто прописал в docker-compose.yml 
extra_host:
  - host.docker.internal:host-gataway

Comment: @user567572 ip-адрес вашего хоста внутри сети докер, он автоматически заменяет на правильный для текущего контейнера, например, 172.17.0.1. данная конструкция позволяет добавлять любые записи например `- "my.host.com:123.123.123.123"`

Comment: Хорошо, буду ещё читать документацию. Вот только нафиг был нужен этот исправленный docker-php-entrypoint? Где-то видел, что через такой исправленный файл подключался xdebug

Comment: Или extra_hosts добавили недавно?